# Embedding youtube video dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, youtube

I want to add dynamic youtube video embedding functionality to my web page, i.e. as soon as user finishes typing youtube url in the textbox, video gets embeded beneath the input box automatically, if the url is valid ofcourse.

I think this can be done with jquery, about which I have least idea. So please help me accordingly.
Any elaborate help is much appreciated.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607808/convert-a-youtube-video-url-to-embed-code

Comment: thanx but i dont want embed to happen after button press...I want it to happen soon after users stops typing or clicks outside the textbox.

Comment: Just append the embedded html code using the event mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1**. We have to know the **trigger event after stop typing**

[How to trigger an event in input text after I stop typing/writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042193/how-to-trigger-an-event-in-input-text-after-i-stop-typing-writing/18484799#18484799)

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
  clearTimeout (timer);
  timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
})();

$('input').keyup(function() {
  delay(function(){
    // Here check if video exists
    // if video exist show it 
  }, 1000 );
});
```

answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2269004/ata-ul-mustafa :

<s>**2**. We have to know if a **youtube video exists**</s>

[How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809067/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-in-client-side)

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+videoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
        alert(data.data.title);
    }).error(function() { alert("error"); });

answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3748701/innomanik

**3**. If video exists show it (in the iframe):

```
<iframe id="myIframe" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
```

**Set** the content of the **src attribute** of the iframe dynamically with **jQuery**:

```
 var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID;
 $('#myIframe').attr('src', url)
```

---

## UPDATE (v3)

Therefore you need an **api key**. How to get it you can read [here](https://elfsight.com/blog/2016/12/how-to-get-youtube-api-key-tutorial/). And read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591788/youtube-api-key-security-how-worried-should-i-be) about security.

```js
var delay = (function() {
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$('#youtubeId').keyup(function() {
  delay(function() {
    var videoID = $('#youtubeId').val();
    var videos = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos";
    var apiKey = "AIzaSyAzYHm1iwMocB9pW2uZrz_6Sqte5t_bXGo"; // Insert here your api key
    var fieldsTitle = "fields=items(snippet(title))";
    var fieldsEmpty = "";
    var part = "part=snippet";

    function getUrl(fields) {
      var url = videos + "?" + "key=" + apiKey + "&" + "id=" + videoID + "&" + fields + "&" + part;
      return url;
    }

    $.get(getUrl(fieldsEmpty), function(response) {
      var status = response.pageInfo.totalResults;
      var title;
      if (status) {
        $.get(getUrl(fieldsTitle), function(response) {
          title = response.items[0].snippet.title;
          $('#info').text(title);
          var url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID;
          $('#myIframe').attr('src', url)
        })
      } else {
        title = "Video doesn't exist";
        $('#info').text(title);
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', "");
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

**Demo**: https://embed.plnkr.co/ixAFtU/

Comment: Thanx a lot bud for being so so patient and helping me.